# rvm command not working

Tags: rvm

I am facing issue while running the following command

```
rvm --default use ruby-2.1.6@metasploit-framework
error - > no comment RVM found
```

Comment: I guess you mean no `command` rvm found ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `rvm` is not installed on your machine , to install it follow this link [How do I install ruby-rvm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128966/how-do-i-install-ruby-rvm).